# React Dropdown Menu Opens All Dropdown Menus at Once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, styled-components

I have created a simple dropdown menu using React hooks.  It works as I want it to with one exception -- it opens up all dropdown menus at once.  This makes sense given that I'm using a single state that I use for all dropdown instances:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
```

I then use onClick (and onBlur) to set the state whenever someone clicks on a dropdown menu:

```
onClick={() => setOpen(state => !state)}
onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}
```

When `open` is set to `true`, the dropdown menu is set to `display: block;`.  When it is false, it is set to `display: none;`  This is set in the css (using Styled Components).

So this all works fine for a single dropdown menu -- the problem is, **every instance of the dropdown menu is connected to the state of `open`** . That means that if open is set to true, then every dropdown menu displays - false, none of them display.

How can I modify the dropdown menu so that I can toggle only the dropdown menu that is being clicked on?

Thanks.

Comment: Create your dropdown as a component, then each one will have it's own open

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to use your Dropdown more than once, then what you should do is to make it as a component so each one controls it's own state.

```js
const Dropdown =() => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    onClick=() => setOpen(state => !state)
    onBlur=() => setOpen(false)
    return (<input onClick={this.onClick}>
        ....
    </input>)
}

const otherComponent = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <Dropdown/>
          <Dropdown/>
       </div>
     )
}
```